# How do you find which row and column a number belongs to in Floyd Triangle

Tags: algorithm, math, pascals-triangle, triangular

How do you find which row and column does a number belongs to in Floyd Triangle?

 `1
 2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55`

For example,

- 33 is in the 8th row and 5th column (input 33 → output 8th row, 5th column)
- 46 is in the 10th row and 1st column
- 27 is in the 7th row and 6th column

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: sorry, seems like it has been removed.

Comment: @AmiTavory, OP presumably started typing tags in and tried with "Floyd". Floyd-Warshall popped up and OP clicked it without knowing exactly what Floyd-Warshall meant. I've removed the tag, your comment is obsolete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that n-th row [ends with value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) `n*(n+1)/2`. So you can make quadratic equation and solve it to get row number for given number k

```
n*(n+1)/2 = k
n^2 + n - 2*k = 0
D = 1 + 8*k
n_row = Ceil((-1 + Sqrt(D)) / 2)   //round float value up
```

For example, for k=33 you can calculate

```
   n_row = Ceil((-1 + Sqrt(265)) / 2) = 
           Ceil(7.639) =
           8
```

Having n_row, find the last number of previous row and position of k in the current row

```
  n_Column = 33 - n_row * (n_row - 1) / 2 = 
            33 - 28 = 
            5
```

Pseudocode for alternative method of row finding:

```
 sum = 0
 row = 0
 while sum < k do
      row++  
      sum = sum + row
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, how to find it recursively without sqrt?

Comment: @beeant Just add numbers 1,2,3... until sum exceeds given number

Comment: I tried to apply the formula into codes. and do you think D = 1-8*k is supposed to be D = 1 + 8 * k ?

Comment: Where do you add the 1, 2, 3?

Comment: sum = 0; 0+1=1; 1+2=3; 3+3 =6; 6+4=10;... (look at my link to Triangular numbers)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123238/discussion-between-beeant-and-mbo).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this approach is somehow more natural:

```
       #include <iostream>
       size_t getRow(size_t n)
       { // just count the rows, and when you meet the number, return the row
           size_t row(0), k(1);
           for (row = 1; row <= n; row++)
           {
               for (size_t j = 1; j <= row; j++)
               {
                   if (k == n)
                   {
                       goto end;
                   }
                   k++;
               }
           }
           end:return row;
       }
       size_t getCol(size_t n)
       { /* well, we have already found the row, so now knowing that every n-th row starts
       with n(n-1)/2+1 and ends with n(n+1)/2, just count the columns and when you
       meet the number (and that surely will happen), just return the column and you're done*/
           size_t col(1);
           size_t r = getRow(n);
           for (size_t j = r * (r - 1) / 2+1; j <= r*(r+1)/2; j++)
           {
               if (j == n)
               {
                   break;
               }
               col++;
           }    
           return col;
       }
       int main()
       {
           size_t n;
           std::cin >> n;
           std::cout << "Number " << n << " lies in row " << getRow(n) << ", column " << getCol(n) << " of the Floyd's triangle.\n";

           return 0;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

In python this looks like this (if you don't want to use `sqrt`):

```
def rc(n):
    # rc(1) = (1, 1); rc(33) -> (8, 5)
    assert n > 0 and int(n) == n
    sum = 0
    row = 0
    while sum < n:
        row += 1
        sum += row
    col = n - sum + row
    return row, col
```