# How to get the adjacent blocks in Floyd triangle?

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, pascals-triangle, triangular

I need to write a function to find the adjacent blocks in Floyd triangle.

`1
 2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55`

What is the formula to find the adjacent blocks (top, left, right, bottom) of a given value.

For example:

- input 20 → output left: 19, right: 21, top: 15, bottom: 26
- input 28 → output left: 27, right: -1, top: -1, bottom: 35
- input 19 → output left: 18, right: 20, top: 14, bottom: 25

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What did you learn from [your previous question on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39467778/2336725)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shifts needed to go up or down are uniquely determined by the identifier o the line. If `n >= 1` in the given value, you have to find the largest integer `k` such that:

```
k(k+1)/2 + 1 <= n <=> k^2 + k + 2(1 - n) <= 0
```

This is a second-degree polynomial function:

```
delta = 1 - 8(1 - n) = 8n - 7 > 0
x1 = (-1 + sqrt(8n-7)) / 2 and x2 = (-1 - sqrt(8n-7)) / 2
```

`x2 < 0 < x1` so the 0-based identifier of the line is: `k := floor((-1 + sqrt(8n-7)) / 2)`.

After  that: up it's `n - k`, down it's `n + k + 1`, left `n - 1` and right `n + 1`. The corner cases (leftmost/rightmost/...) can be spotted with `k` as well, left to the reader. ;)

Comment: @beeant: Every algorithm can be made "artificially" recursive, but I have to say I don't see any natural recursive substructure here... Why do you want to use recursion?

Comment: do you think there's a recursive substructure on the function for finding k?

Comment: @beeant   I gave you iterative code in previous topic. Have you seen it?

Comment: where is the previous topic?
Right now I just use binary search to find the k.